# Does sphinx provide any way to include math equation from a separate file?

Tags: python-sphinx

Is there anything similar to the [literalinclude](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html#directive-literalinclude) directive but that works to include [math equations](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/math.html#role-math) from a separate file instead of source code?

Comment: Why not use literalinclude and include a file that includes a math equation as in the example to which you linked? Either that, or clarify your question.

Comment: Isn't literalinclude only for source code? None of the examples in that link show anything else.

Comment: If the external file contains math (LaTeX) markup only and you want it to be nicely rendered, then I don't see an obvious solution. `literalinclude` works, but the math content will not be formatted. But if the math markup is provided as the content of a `math` directive in the external file, then you can use `include` to pull it in.